# tensorflow get size of string_input_producer

Tags: python, tensorflow

How do I check the number of filenames string_input_producer has read? Different operations will be performed depending on size in input data so I need to know how many images will be read or have been read.

Code below not telling me how much images I have read or am about to read.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make a queue of file names including all the JPEG images files in the relative image directory.
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(tf.train.match_filenames_once("./MNIST_data/*.png"))

reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

image = tf.image.decode_png(value) # use png or jpg decoder based on your files.

num_preprocess_threads = 1
min_queue_examples = 256
batch_size=2;
images = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image], batch_size, min_queue_examples + 3 * batch_size, num_threads=num_preprocess_threads, min_after_dequeue=min_queue_examples)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
  t_image = image.eval() #here is your image Tensor :) 
  fig = plt.figure()
  plt.imshow(t_image)
  plt.show()

  coord.request_stop()
  coord.join(threads)
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions like `string_input_producer` will add a queue to current graph which can only **dequeue only one example** each time. Usually the output tensors will be feed to functions like `tf.train.shuffle_batch` which is what you want. The argument `batch_size` of this function can control how many examples each time dequeued as the input of of your model

UPDATE:

if you want to check whether your input data is correct, you can run it out with `sess.run(my_img)` which will give you a numpy.array tensor. You can directly look at the element of this tensor or just plot it with `matplotlib`.

make sure you have already started queue runners before `sess.run` or your program will hang forever

Comment: do you have an algorithm for your answer ? i edited my code to include shuffle_batch but im getting error. can you show full code to read image then plot ? please fensortlow is hardd

Comment: which kind of error you got? I looked at your code, I think it is ok

Comment: it is saying all shapes must be fully defined. the error is pointing to tf.train.shuffle_batch

Comment: Oh I know what's wrong with your code, the input to `shuffle_batch`(also is the output of `string_input_producer`) should be fully defined, so after this line `image = tf.image.decode_png(value)`, add `image.set_shape(your_shape)` to your program and it should be ok. note that `your_shape` should be correctly match the true shape of `image` or program will go wrong. as far as I know, tf could possibly flatten your image into a vector, just try  a three dim shape and one dim shape and see which one is correct.

Comment: im getting an error it says set_shape invalid syntax. can you post your code that is working ? i basically have a file with 1000 png images that i want to read by batch then verify it is correct by printing the size or displaying the image.

Comment: see my [code](https://github.com/zakizhou/mnist_input_pipeline/blob/master/mnist_input.py) that does this especially `read_and_decode` function.

Answer (score 0):

`string_input_producer` returns you back a standard [FIFOQueue](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/FIFOQue) (it returns you an [`input_producer`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/python/training/input.py#L226) and it returns you a [queue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/python/training/input.py#L172).

A FIFOQueue does not have information about the number of elements it has read, only the number of elements are currently in a queue (`q.size()`). If you want to know how many element has been read you need to manually add a counter which you will increment each time you read an element.